# Assigning values to a 2D array , using mouse clicks on a screen at monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, mouse-position

I am working on a level editor for my game, developed by C# , using Monogame.
There is a 2D matrix which represents the map itself , each cell is a 64 pixel unit. 
When loading the background , coordinates are shown on top of the screen, see example below.
At first, the 2D matrix is set to 0 at each cell, by default.
**What i need is , by clicking objects at the screen using the left mouse
button , to set a different value to the cell which corresponds to it at the matrix.**
Thats how i define obstacles at the game , which later on will be defined as collisions for the player when hitting them.
For example , to define a ceiling, i would need to click several objects at the top of the screen one by another , at the same row .
As an example, for a 640X192 background image,  the matrix it would look like the example below 
(Since width is width/64 , and height is height/64)

```
{
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
 }
```

See example here for the screen and the coordinates:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbUHJ.jpg 
Thanks alot for any help !

```
   class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D gameBackround;
    SpriteFont font;
    int[,] map ;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
        graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.HiDef;

    }




    protected override void LoadContent()
    {


        this.IsMouseVisible = true;
        gameBackround = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level_01_A");//this is the background

    map = new int[gameBackround.Width / 64, gameBackround.Height / 64];

        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/Font");
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }          

      protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(gameBackround, new Rectangle(0, -700, 3840, 1984), Color.White);
        DrawGrid(map, spriteBatch, font);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }

             public void DrawGrid(int[,] gameMap, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont f)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gameMap.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameMap.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(f, x + " / " + y, new Vector2(x * 64, y * 64), Color.White);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Detect a click and get the position of the mouse cursor
- Convert the positions's X and Y co-ordinates to indices for your 2D array
- Index the array and amend the values as required

First you need to get the mouse's state using [`Mouse.GetState`](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/mouse-input).

You can then detect mouse clicks like so:

```
var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    // do something here
}
```

`mouseState` has `X` and `Y` members, which gets you the mouse cursor's position relative to the top-left corner of the game window.

You need to convert this position to array indices. To do this, divide the X and Y components by the size of the tiles - 64 in your case:

```
var xIndex = mouseState.X / 64;
var yIndex = mouseState.Y / 64;
```

You can then amend your array as you see fit:

```
map[xIndex, yIndex] = 1;
```

You'll want to do some bounds checking also, to ensure the indices you calculate are actually in the array.

Lower bounds check is trivial - just check if `xIndex` and `yIndex` are greater than zero.

For upper bounds check, use the [`GetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=netframework-4.8) property to get the length of each dimension of your array. Then assert that `xIndex` and `yIndex` are less than those values:

```
if (xIndex >= 0 && xIndex < map.GetLength(0) && yIndex >= 0 && yIndex < map.GetLength(1)) {
  map[xIndex][yIndex] = 1;
}
```

All together something like this in your `Update` method should work:

```
var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
  var xIndex = mouseState.X / 64;
  var yIndex = mouseState.Y / 64;

  if (xIndex >= 0 && xIndex < map.GetLength(0) && yIndex >= 0 && yIndex < map.GetLength(1)) {
    map[xIndex][yIndex] = 1;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps